# reference assemblies installed with dotnet add package in f#

Tags: f#, dotnet-cli

I installed `Akka.Cluster` with `dotnet add package Akka.Cluster` and I'm trying to add the reference to an F# Script file.

After a long search [I found: The default package location is ~/.nuget/packages on macOS and Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package#options)

I use :

```ml
#r @"/Users/{myusername}/.nuget/packages/akka.cluster/1.4.10/lib/netstandard2.0/Akka.Cluster.dll"
```

In all tutorials I see people use `#r @"../packages/` instead of `#r @"/Users/{myusername}/.nuget/packages/"`

Another alternative I found is using `#r @"bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Akkling.Cluster.dll"`, but I'm not sure this is a good practice.

Is there a shorter version than `#r @"/Users/{myusername}/.nuget/packages/...` to add packages?

(I know .NET 5 will bring `#r "nuget:..."`)

Comment: `#r "nuget:..."` already can be used without .NET 5. Would [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801070/5246145) help you?

Comment: well it says it need `--langversion:preview` so that's .NET 5, right?

Comment: No, it's just a setting for VS Code (you can pass it directly to fsi). It's running fine on .NET Core 3.1 on my machine.

Comment: its not recognized by Rider tho