# How to use AKKA in a F# source file (*.fs)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, actor, akka.net

I can use AKKA actors with F# in a .fsx file within Visual Studio Code normally, but when I use them in a .fs file, it reports an error:

> error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Akka' is not defined.

Even if I have downloaded the AKKA packages with `dotnet add Project package Akka` and `dotnet add Project package Akka.FSharp --version 1.4.10` in my project, and included them in .fs file:

```
module P

open System
open Akka
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.FSharp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include Akka.net framework for F# in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800694/how-to-include-akka-net-framework-for-f-in-vscode)

Comment: Thank you! But we have tried this, and it does not work.

Comment: More detail, please.

Comment: In your post, please.

Comment: In the .fsx file, we are going to call a function defined in a .fs file. For example, in Protocol.fs, we define a module P and a function "work" inside. In project.fsx, we need to use P.work. And both of these 2 files need to open Akka. This error may be caused when we try to compile the .fs files in an interactive way. We are wondering if there is any other way to do this, or we just cannot use the .fsx and .fs files at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly refer to `fs` files from from `fsx` files, as it is a fairly common workflow for rapid prototyping. You can use `#if INTERACTIVE` and `#endif` pragma to separate the compiled and fsx code portions if necessary.

This goes into `Library.fs`, the project has referenced and downloaded the `FileHelpers` nuget package:

```
module SO201004.Library
open FileHelpers

let fname = @"C:\temp\navdb.csv"

[<CLIMutable; DelimitedRecord(",")>]
type NavDB = {
    Path: string
    Frequency: string
    LastAccess: string
}

let fHelper = FileHelperEngine<NavDB>()
let navDB = fHelper.ReadFile(fname)
```

Now in your `Script1.fsx` file you can `#load` the above module, and also `#r` any additional libraries:

```
#r @"C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\filehelpers\3.4.1\lib\netstandard2.0\FileHelpers.dll"
//#r "nuget: FileHelpers"
#load "Library.fs"

open SO201004

Library.navDB
```

I am just opening the `SO201004` namespace  to access the `Library` module. If I call `navDB` I get back the parsed CSV (the parser is defined in the `Library` file/module).

> ```
> { Path = ""C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Documents\Source\WebDev\FruitsProject""
>   Frequency = ""364""
>   LastAccess = ""132160581961691649"" };
> { Path =
>         ""C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Documents\Source\WebDev\todolist-v2-starting-files""
>   Frequency = ""12""
>   LastAccess = ""132161111431384871"" }|]
> ```

In the preview version you should be able to use the `#r nuget:` directive I commented out.